# Wrappers float is affecting the A tags hover area

Tags: html, css

I'm sure this is something simple but I am just not seeing it.
My wrapper DIV is floating left and the A tags within are displaying correctly but mousing over them you'll see that they are not the proper height/width.

I can't seem to get them in line, could someone take a quick look and tell me what I am missing?

[Page is here, it's the social media icons](http://www.lebondachat.com/)

Any help is greatly appreciated, again I am sure it's something simple.

--Edit--

I am on a Mac, tested with firefox and safari so far, they don't hover correctly, only the very bottom portion of them actually function as a button.

In firebug, if I remove the wrappers float attribute, the links hover as they should. So I know it has something to do with the float.

Comment: Right, but the icons only act as links near the bottom of the image, instead of the entire image as he is looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Chrome the icons are in a line but, as you said, only the bottom portion of them is active. The problem is that your #branding element extends down below the bottom of #main, partially obscuring #subWrapper, #sub, #left, and part of #right (though not enough to cause a problem there).

You could put `overflow: hidden` on #main, but then the graphic in #branding would get cut off at the bottom. (The graphics look very nice, BTW.) I think if you just add a positive z-index to either #sub or #subWrapper, such as `z-index: 1`, that should do the trick.

Comment: Ok you are definitely right, that is the problem. When I push the branding up it fixes the problem. I have tried changing the z-index with no luck yet, I have never had to work with z-index before. Finally a chance to use it. I will fumble my way around and hopefully find out how to get this thing displaying correctly, thank you very much for the help (and the compliment!) =)

Comment: Got it! Crazy thing is, I didnt even touch z-index. After reading a nice lil article on [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/) I saw mentioned the "natural" index order. By using position: relative; i pushed it up in that natural order and got it to work. Thanks again for getting me on the right path!